Почему не берутся данные из Props при вызове функции ПО КЛИКУ?
В общем схема такая:
Есть файлы - App(родительский Компонент) / СharList(список карточек) / CharInfo(блок с инфой той карточки, на которую кликнули)
В App находятся 2 других компонента, общий state, с которым они работают и функция, которая записывает в этот state id-шник
Эту функцию я передал в СharList, и по клику на карточки, рендерящиеся в СharList - через 'state-lifting' происходит запись id конкретной карточки в общий state, который в App.
В свою очередь, компонент CharInfo получает в свои Props эту инфу(id) из общего State из App, получает, записывает уже в СВОЙ state - делает запрос на сервер уже по полученному id.
То есть схема такая - кликаешь на карточку в СharList => её id записывается в родительский state в App => оттуда его себе в Пропсы берёт CharInfo, делает по нему запрос, ну и рендерит полученный результат.
// App
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import CharList from "../charList/CharList";
import CharInfo from "../charInfo/CharInfo";

class App extends Component{

// начальный рандомный id, чтобы в CharList при загрузке страницы не было пусто
state = {
    characterId: 1017295,
}

setCharacterId = async (id) => {
    await this.setState({characterId: id})
}

render(){
    return (
        <div className="app">
               <CharList setCharacterId={this.setCharacterId}/>
               <CharInfo characterData={this.state}/> 
        </div>
    )
  }

}
export default App;




//CharList 
import React, {Component} from 'react';
class CharList extends Component{
state = {
    dataCards: {}
}

//  СПИСОК КАРТОЧЕК
charInfo = new CharInfo() // Класс с функцией cardRender()
render(){
    const cardDataList = Array.from(this.state.dataCards);  
    const cards = cardDataList.map(card => {
        return (
                <li 
                    className="char__item" 
                    key={card.id} 
                    // State-lifting - по клику вызываем Функцию, которая передаёт в ГЛОБАЛЬНЫЙ State конкретный id
                    onClick={() => {this.props.setCharacterId(card.id); this.charInfo.cardRender()}} // ОШИБКА во 2й Функц., почему то в componentDidMount() - cardRender() работает. А при кликах - нет
                    > 
                    <img src={image} alt="abyss"/>
                    <h3 className="char__name">{name}</h3>
                    <p className='char__descr'>{description}</p>
                </li>
        )
    }) 

    return(
        <ul className="char__list">
            {cards}
        </ul>
    )
  }

}
export default CharList;




//CharInfo 
import { Component } from 'react';
import Resource from '../../api/data.jsx';

class CharInfo extends Component{

state = {

}

cardData = new Resource() // Класс в котором хранятся Функции, делающие ЗАПРОСЫ НА СЕРВЕР
cardRender = async () => {
    await this.cardData.getOneCharackter(this.props.characterData['characterId']).then(
        data => {
            this.setState(
                    {name: data.data.results[0].name,
                    description: data.data.results[0].description ? data.data.results[0].description : 'NO DATA',
                    image: data.data.results[0].thumbnail.path + '.' + data.data.results[0].thumbnail.extension,
                    homepage: data.data.results[0].urls[0].url,
                    wiki: data.data.results[0].urls[0].url,}
            )
        }
    )
}

// Начальный запуск cardRender() при "монтировании"  - cardRender работает. А вот при клике из CharList - нет
componentDidMount(){
    this.cardRender()
}

render(){
    const cardState = this.state;
    return (
        <div className="char__info">
            <div className="char__basics">
                <img src={cardState.image} alt="abyss"/>
                <div>
                    <div className="char__info-name">{cardState.name}</div>
                    <div className="char__btns">
                        <a href={cardState.homepage} className="button button__main">
                            <div className="inner">homepage</div>
                        </a>
                        <a href={cardState.wiki} className="button button__secondary">
                            <div className="inner">wiki</div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="char__descr">
                {cardState.description}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
  }

}
export default CharInfo;

И ВОТ В ЧЁМ ПРОБЛЕМА: в CharInfo функция, которая берёт переданные props из App и по ним рендерит результат - это cardRender(). Изначально при загрузке страницы она запускается в componentDidMount() и ВСЁ РАБОТАЕТ.
Ошибка происходит ПРИ КЛИКЕ на карточку из СharList, а точнее - почему то функция не видит prop characterData(30 строчка в App). При чём в консоли разраба видно, что characterData передан, но почему то функция при клике не может его прочитать, и видит его как undefined:

Я лично думаю, что ошибка в файле CharList - в строчке, где вызываются 2 функции на onClick()
Вот так вот. Понимаю, что наверное не очень всё понятно, но там такой принцип, что текстом сложно объяснить, я постарался сделать понятней, например удалил часть кода из CharList - вам просто стоит знать, что этот компонент создаёт список карточек.
Если что спрашивайте, поясню что там за что отвечает) ну и буду очень благодарен за помощь, сам что-то не пойму, как это исправить
